# Django find items from db by values from list?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-queryset

I have a list of strings:

```
phrases_filter = json.loads(request.GET['phrases_filter'])
['xx', 'yy']
```

I need to lookup all phrases in db, that contain `xx` **OR** `yy`

I tried it like this:

```
Phrase.objects.filter(name__in phrases_filter)
```

But this gave me only phrases that have in name `xx` **AND** `yy`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can *unroll* the list, and define a set of `__contains` predicate with or-logic:

```
from django.db.models import Q
from functools import reduce
from operator import or_

Phrase.objects.filter(
    reduce(or_, (Q(name__contains=e) for e in phrases_filter))
)
```

In the case of the given `phrases_filter`, we will generate something equivalent to:

```
Phrase.objects.filter(
    Q(name__contains='xx') | Q(name__contains='yy')
)
```

So `reduce(..)` will operate on a *generator* of `Q(..)` objects, here `[Q(name__contains='xx'), Q(name__contains='yy')]`. The `reduce(..)` works like what is known in *functional programming* as a "*fold*" (which is a special case of a *catamorphism*).

We thus will add `or_`s in between, resulting in `Q(name__contains='xx') | Q(name__contains='yy')`. This is an object that basically encodes a filter condition: it means that the `name` column should `__contains` the substring `'xx'`, or the substring `'yy'`.

> **Note**: in case you want to match case *in*sensitive (so rows with `XX`, or `Xx`, or `xX`, or `xx` are *all* candidates), then replace `__contains` with `__icontains`.

**EDIT**: based on your comment, in case `phrases_filter` is empty, you want all rows to match, we can do this by using an `if` statement:

```
from django.db.models import Q
from functools import reduce
from operator import or_

queryset = Phrase.objects.all()
if phrases_filter:
    queryset = filter(
        reduce(or_, (Q(name__contains=e) for e in phrases_filter))
    )
```

So only in case `phrases_filter` contains *at least* on element, we perform a filtering.

Comment: can you explain it line by line, I don't really understand how it works and what does this mean

Comment: and this phrases_filter also can be empty

Comment: @user2950593: in case it is empty, then what should happen? No matches, or all rows match?

Comment: all rows match=)

Comment: okay, seems to be working=) is this a preferebla way to do this task?

Comment: @user2950593: well as far as I know there is no specific filter. Another approach might be to use a regex, but this will probably only efficient in case the list is rather large.